# I have some premade backgrounds in various sizes, I don't know what drawable folders they should go in or should I create custom ones?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

Bit of a basic question, apologies for that. The problem is this the first time someone else has made background images for me. So I went a bit fancy with it and they produced them in various sizes for me. Normally I keep it simple with one flat colour which of course requires zero work. The main problem is the whole pixel/dp thing. I used a converter but it shows me all the densities so that confused me further. Here are the sizes I am playing with:

```
480x800px
540x960px
720x1280px
768x1280px
800x1280px
```

Can I just create a drawable-sw480dp for the first image for example and then put it in there? drawable-sw540dp for the next one, etc?

Apologies for what may be a basic question, stayed away from custom backgrounds during most of my dev time.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: if you have a flat color, use a Color instead of putting a whole drawable. It not zero work

Comment: @blackbelt I've used flat colours in my past apps is what I'm saying. This is the first time I'm working with a custom drawable as a background.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
This link also may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supporting HDPI and XHDPI devices only for the time being so I converted them all to do based on HDPI then built drawable swXdp folders based on them. So it looks to have worked since the background looks really good on a XHDPI device I own. I will accept this as my answer at the some point but if anyone sees this in the future, it may not be entirely correct.